# Get Unique String from a longer string when the unique string is at 2 different locations

Tags: html, regex, string, dom

In a web application that I am creating tests for, there are 2 sets of strings from which I wish to get a substring (which is unique) to use for identifying that element on the Web Page:

Parent Form:

```
InputText-eLeType-AQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVWZ-bMs-bms_9999999_3512-bMs-obj-bMsDot-com-bMsDot-bmssolutions-bMsDot-COMPONENT-bMsDot-bms_9999999_109-bMs-textField-bMs-ABNylGGXXu8IPwjI4jMM5y1K
```

SubForm:

```
InputText-eLeType-AQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVXJ-bMs-bms_FK_9999999_406_ID-bMs-obj-bMsDot-com-bMsDot-bmssolutions-bMsDot-COMPONENT-bMsDot-bms_9999999_177-bMs-searchLookupField-bMs-ABNylGGXXu8IPwjI4jMM5y1K-bMs-AQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVWZ-bMs-PRIMARY9999999_480-bMs-obj-bMsDot-com-bMsDot-bmssolutions-bMsDot-COMPONENT-bMsDot-bms_9999999_109
```

I wish to get the substring from both of these using a single function, so that I don't have to create a different functions for each type I encounter:

Substring in the above 2 provided strings is:

```
ABNylGGXXu8IPwjI4jMM5y1K
```

This substring can change for each element on the web page, but is unique for each element of the page and so useful to identify.

I cannot use the full string, as it changes for each environment or if I generate a new environment to host the web pages (the complete string depends on the Meta Data).

We tried doing it for the Parent Form, by using the "-" as the delimiter and identifying the last -bMs- and then taking the string, but that does not work for the SubForm.

So, my main question is, is there some RegEx that can be created to extract only that string (composed of alphabets [upper & lower case] and numbers) from the full string? Or some other simpler way to identify that string?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a combination of `positive Lookbehind`, `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]`. Try this code:

```
(?<=-bMs-)[A-Z]{3}[a-z]\w+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/YUZiFa/1

It seems to work without even the `positive Lookbehind`

```
[A-Z]{3}[a-z]\w+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/YUZiFa/2

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to base the selection of the elements on the previous one, then this might work for you:

```
(?<=searchLookupField-bMs-|textField-bMs-)\w+
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/MXpqWK/1)

And if you wanted to be extra certain, you could append a second lookahead to the end.

```
(?<=searchLookupField-bMs-|textField-bMs-)\w+(?=-bMs-|$)
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/MXpqWK/2)

If these don't work, or if the whole string varies greatly, then some more examples would help us narrow it down and come up with a great answer!